# What does Bold method mean in Eclipse outline view?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse (I use Java), the Outline View shows a few methods right now in **Bold**...

what does this mean?

does it just mean I have been editing them? I edited a few methods and the ones in bold are some (but not all) that I edited...

[image]

Comment: What Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: Kepler... installed only a month ago, so I guess it's latest version

Comment: A screenshot would be great

Comment: ok, I just uploaded one

Comment: No idea really, using Junos here, not having any method shown bold in outline view. Maybe you searched something and that is the hit ? Check out Search view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using Mylyn. Mylyn saves for your current task which files/classes/methods you have worked on. So in this case bold means: "You have worked on task X ... and for this task you have looked at/edited `Database.getBooleanFromRow`.

Comment: ah, thanks I was just experimenting with this mylyn the other day but don't really understand it yet... will have to research further